# How can I determine the number of confirmations of a transaction and its fee using the Blockchain.info DATA API?

Tags: confirmations, blockchain.info, transaction-fees

How can I know if any given transaction has confirmations and has paid the miner's fee, using the [BlockChain.info DATA API](https://blockchain.info/api/blockchain_api)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If a transaction returned from the `http://blockchain.info/rawtx/$tx_hash` endpoint has a confirmation, it will have a `block_height` member. You can then calculate roughly its number of confirmations by subtracting that value from the latest height retrieved from the `http://blockchain.info/latestblock` endpoint.

Code example, in Ruby:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require "open-uri"
require "json"
# call this script with `ruby block_height.rb <tx_hash>`
tx = ARGV.shift
puts "Getting info for #{tx}..."
j = JSON.parse open("http://blockchain.info/rawtx/#{tx}").read
if j["block_height"]
  b = JSON.parse open("http://blockchain.info/latestblock").read
  puts "%d confirmations" % (b["height"] - j["block_height"] + 1)
else
  time_since = Time.now.gmtime.to_i - j["time"]
  puts "It's been #{time_since} seconds since the transaction was created."
  puts "It's not been ten minutes yet!" if time_since < 600
  puts "It's due any time now." if time_since >= 600
end
```

Calculating the transaction fee is best done by summing the inputs and outputs of a transaction, then subtracting the inputs from the outputs. Difference is the transaction fee.

Comment: Hi Colin! Thanks a lot! Could you expand a bit on the block_height part?

Comment: Added a code example for you.

Comment: verifies but just out of curiosity, how do I explain the relations between the number of confirmations, the tx block height and the latest block height?

Comment: number of confirmations = latest block height - tx block height

Answer (score 2):

I have created a simple php function with my basic knowledge of php.
here

> function get_tx_confirmation($tx_hash_id){
>       $raw_lastest_block= json_decode(file_get_contents("https://blockchain.info/latestblock"), true);
>    $lastest_block=$raw_lastest_block["height"];
>    $raw_tx=json_decode(file_get_contents("https://blockchain.info/rawtx/$tx_hash_id"), true);
>    $tx_block_height=$raw_tx["block_height"];
>        $confirmations = $lastest_block - $tx_block_height +1;
>   return $confirmations;
>       }

Comment: This is just to get the amount of transactions using the hash id